# Controller not able to bind form array to model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have this in my cshtml:

```
        <div class="row checkbox-group">
            @foreach (var category in Model._categories)
            {
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="@category.Description">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ChosenCategories[]" value="@category.Id" id="checkbox-@category.Id" />
                    <label class=" btn btn-flat" for="checkbox-@category.Id">
                        <i class="material-icons-round">
                            @category.Icon
                        </i>@category.Name
                    </label>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

Using serializeArray to send data

```
formData = $('form').serializeArray();
```

I can confirm that data is sent like this in the console.

```
0: {name: 'ChosenCategories[]', value: '1005'}
1: {name: 'ChosenCategories[]', value: '1006'}
2: {name: 'ChosenCategories[]', value: '1009'}
3: {name: 'ChosenCategories[]', value: '1010'}
```

But in the controller the model binding and the Request.Form["ChosenCategories"] is also empty.

The important part of the model is like this:

```
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            ChosenCategories = new HashSet<ChosenCategories >();
        }
        public virtual ICollection<ChosenCategories > ChosenCategories { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to bind ChosenCategories[] to my model, but it is not working. The data in the controller(Request.Form["ChosenCategories"]) comes out blank.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo to pass an array to action with ajax:

view:

```
<div class="row checkbox-group">
            @{var i=0;}
            @foreach (var category in Model._categories)
            {
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="@category.Description">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ChosenCategories[@i]" value="@category.Id" id="checkbox-@category.Id" />
                    <label class=" btn btn-flat" for="checkbox-@category.Id">
                        <i class="material-icons-round">
                            @category.Icon
                        </i>@category.Name
                    </label>
                </div>
                i++;
            }
        </div>
```

So that your array will be:

```
0: {name: 'ChosenCategories[0]', value: '1005'}
1: {name: 'ChosenCategories[1]', value: '1006'}
2: {name: 'ChosenCategories[2]', value: '1009'}
3: {name: 'ChosenCategories[3]', value: '1010'}
```

ajax(If you want to pass array in ajax,you need to use json type data):

```
function test() {
            var s = $("#test").serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                url: "Test",
                type: 'post',
                data: JSON.stringify(s),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {

                    //end of Ajax
                }
            });
        }
```

action:

```
public IActionResult Test([FromBody]List<Category> l)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Category:

```
public class Category {
        public int value { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

    }
```